# Fade Out/Fade In of List Items

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, unordered

This is for a "Meet Our Staff" page where there is a vertical unordered list of small images associated with a staff member (#staffDirectory). When the user clicks a different staff member than the one displayed, I want the current large listitem (which includes an image and info about the member - and is assigned the class "staffSelected" and is displayed in the div #staffMember) to fadeOut, lose the class, then take the corresponding listitem (the one the user clicked in #staffDirectory), fadeIn that one, and add the "staffSelected" class.

What is happening now is that there is an overlap and the new listitem briefly displays to the right of the old one (but this only happens the second and subsequent times I click from the #staffDirectory list - the first time works beautifully). So, the transitions are not smooth. I assume this issue has to deal with my declaration of the newMember variable or its use in the fadeIn method.

JS and CSS are below. Thanks in advance.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#staffDirectory ul li").click(function()
    {
        var index = $("#staffDirectory ul li").index(this);
        var newMember = null;
        newMember = $("#staffMember ul li").get(index);

        $(".staffSelected").fadeOut(500, function()     
        {
            $(newMember).fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        });

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
#staffContainer
{
    margin-top: 45px;
}
#staffDirectory
{
    margin: 25px;
    float: left;
}
#staffDirectory ul
{
    list-style:none;
}
#staffDirectory ul li
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#staffDirectory img{
    width: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#staffDirectory li:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.selectedMember {
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
}

#staffMember{

}

#staffMember ul{

list-style: none;
}

#staffMember li{
display: inline;
}

.staffMemberImage {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.staffName {
color: #7F0037;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

.staffSelected {
    display: inherit;
}

#staffMember li:not(.staffSelected) {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="staffDirectory">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selectedMember"><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li>             
                    <li><img src="img/silhouette.jpg"></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="staffMember">
                <ul>
                    <li class="staffSelected">
                        <img src="img/silhouette.jpg" class="staffMemberImage">
                        <p class="staffName">Jane Doe 1</p>
                        <p class="staffDesc">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.
                        </p>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="img/silhouette.jpg" class="staffMemberImage">
                        <p class="staffName">Jane Doe 2</p>
                        <p class="staffDesc">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.
                        </p>
                    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

EDIT:
From Firebug (I would post an image, but I'm new to the site):

```
<div id="staffMember">
<ul>
<li class="" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
<li class="" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
<li class="" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
<li class="" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
**<li class="staffSelected" style="display: list-item; opacity: 1;">
<li class="staffSelected" style="display: list-item; opacity: 1;">**
<img class="staffMemberImage" src="img/silhouette.jpg">
<p class="staffName">Jane Doe</p>
<p class="staffDesc"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus. Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus. Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus. Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque. </p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you also need to remove `staffSelected` from the old one. I took ajgiv's jsfiddle and changed it so it worked:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MC6B2/1/)**

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#staffDirectory ul li").click(function () {
        var index = $("#staffDirectory ul li").index(this);
        var newMember = null;
        newMember = $("#staffMember ul li").get(index);

        $(".staffSelected").stop().fadeOut(500).removeClass('staffSelected');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(newMember).stop().fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in fiddle, this doesn't work (or at least, there's no way to know if it works) because there's nothing to click to set off the event. 
Regardless, I implemented your changes to my code and it works for the most part, but I can still get the overlap to occur. My head's raw from scratching.

Comment: just click on the 'image'. and what browser are you using, it works in Chrome.

Comment: I'm using FF, but I got the same problem in Chrome. To reproduce, continuously click through the listitems before the animation completes.  
RE: image, it tells me that I need a 10 point reputation before adding images.

Comment: One note: I actually have six list items in the staffDirectory. I shortened it to two for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using setTimeout?

```
$(".staffSelected").fadeOut(500, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(newMember).fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        }, 500);
    });
```

Edit:
does this achieve what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/agroth3/MC6B2/

Comment: That does work better, but there's one glitch. If I click a listitem from the #staffDirectory before the animation completes, I end up seeing both. How do I stop/cancel that animation if the user clicks before the animation completes?

Comment: I added these statements at the top of the event handler, but I'm still getting the same thing.

$("#staffMember").stop();
  $("#staffMember ul li:not(.staffSelected)").css("display", "none");

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: No. Or at least I don't know how to capture traffic using a local html file.

Comment: i meant a jsfiddle, not fiddler :P

Comment: Ok, I've never used it before, so pardon my ignorance, but how do you include local files (images)?

Comment: just use a placeholder, something instead of the image, don't need it to be exact, just something similar to your project

Comment: I added the HTML to the post. I can't get jsfiddle to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the events wouldn't fire.