# hide divs and highlighting selected thumbnail to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a team members page and I used this thread to help me out a little.

[Fade Out/Fade In of List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463560/fade-out-fade-in-of-list-items)

I have everything working as I want except I can't figure out how to make the other people in 
my gallery stay active (red border) and hide the other description of the team members on page load. ( On page load scroll down to see what I mean. )

Here is the code I'm working with.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_6">
    <div id="staffDirectory">
        <ul class="team list-image clearfix">
        <li class="selectedMember">
            <img src="images/team/head1.jpg" class="max-img headshots" />
        </li>
        <li><img src="images/team/head2.jpg" class="max-img headshots" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/team/head3.jpg" class="max-img headshots" /></li>
        ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--End 6-->

<div class="grid_6">

<div id="staffMember">
<ul>
    <li class="staffSelected">
        <div class="box white-bg">
        <img src="images/team/head1.jpg" class="headshots-red" />
        <h2 class="red3-tx bold">John Doe 1</h2>
        <h3 class="blue4-tx" style="font-weight:400; font-style:italic;">Position: Manager</h3>
        <p class="blue3-tx">text</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#staffDirectory ul li
{
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#staffDirectory li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.selectedMember {
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
}

.staffSelected {
    display: inherit;
}

#staffMember li:not(.staffSelected) {
    display: none;
}

.team li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 8%;
    width:28%;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.headshots{
    border:5px solid #034A68;
}

.headshots:hover{
border:5px solid #981B1E;   

}

.headshots:active{
    border:5px solid #981B1E;
}

.headshots-red{
    border:5px solid #981B1E;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    height: auto;
    width: 98%; 
}
```

**JS**

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#staffDirectory ul li").click(function()
    {
        var index = $("#staffDirectory ul li").index(this);
        var newMember = null;
        newMember = $("#staffMember ul li").get(index);

        $(".staffSelected").fadeOut(500); 

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(newMember).fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Sorry for the code dumb, just not sure where the problem is.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

**EDIT!!! WORKING VERSION**
Here is the completed working version of this employee gallery. Thank you to the people that helped me out. Hope someone else can find this useful.
http://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/ctHru

Comment: Don't link to your website to demonstrate problems, once the problem is solved it's no longer demonstrated on your site (assuming you fix the problem). Please, if you want to *show* your code (with its problems) please show a live demo at a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, where we can *see* and easily *edit* the code (as opposed to digging through the DOM with developer tools in our browsers).

Comment: @David Thomas okay will do

Comment: im not to sure what you mean, could you screen shot the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all: Red border.

**CSS**

```
.selectedMember>img {
     border-color: #981B1E;
}
```

Second: Hide unselected team members

**CSS**

```
#staffMember li {
   display:none;
}

#staffMember li.staffSelected {
   display:inherit;
}
```

**Note that you created the second #staffMember with the 'staffSelected' class. Only the first one has to have it..**

**EDIT**
Try this JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#staffDirectory ul li").click(function()
    {
        var index = $("#staffDirectory ul li").index(this);
        $('.staffSelected').fadeOut(500);
        $('.selectedMember').removeClass('selectedMember');
        $(this).addClass('selectedMember');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.staffSelected').removeClass('staffSelected');
            $("#staffMember ul li:eq("+index+")").fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: That helped alot, but only made the first member active. Not the others.

Comment: @Divey Yes that worked I only had to add in ` $("#staffDirectory ul li:first-child").click();` from  Divey

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help. Much appreciated. I will make a Jsfiddle to showcase the solution to the problem. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

Try simulating a click event on the first element of the directory after you define the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#staffDirectory ul li").click(function() {
        var index = $("#staffDirectory ul li").index(this), 
            newMember = $("#staffMember ul li").get(index);

        $(".staffSelected").fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('staffSelected');
            $(newMember).fadeIn(500).addClass('staffSelected');
        });
    });

    $("#staffDirectory ul li:first-child").click();
});
```

Comment: that fixed my on load problem but it does a weird flicker on page load now.

Comment: I'm just going to update my website for the moment If it get fix I will make a proper jsfiddle. Not alot of time at the moment.

Comment: When the page loads, it looks like each `#staffMember`  list item has  the `.staffSelected` class. Remove that, let your javascript handle that piece, and it should fix the flicker.

Comment: @ Divey Yup that fixed the flicker.

Comment: @ Divey Also I only used this section ` $("#staffDirectory ul li:first-child").click();` as using the whole script made it break.